# Can't bind or render Rich Text from REST with Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, knockout.js

I'm getting data back and it does render Title, but can't seem to render rich text.

markup:

```
<div id="bodyarea">
    <div data-bind=foreach:list>
        <span data-bind="text:Title" />
        <div data-bind="html: RichData"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <p id="myarea"></p>
```

ko:

```
function LoadLists() {
    var listItems = [];
    var count = 0;
    $.getJSON("https://myserver.com/sites/knockout/_api/lists/getbytitle('List%20One')/items?$filter=Title eq 

'zzzz'",

        function (data, textstatus, jqXHR) {

            $(data.value).each(function (index, item) {
                count++;
                var koItem = {};
                koItem.Title = item.Title;
                koItem.RichData = item.Rich;


                listItems.push(koItem);

                if (data.value.length == count) {
                    var vm =
                                    {
                                        list: ko.observableArray(listItems)
                                    };
                    ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("bodyarea"));
                }

            })
        });


}
$(document).ready(function () { LoadLists(); });
```

Comment: setting value to an observable in knockoutout should be done as function call as observables are functions. Not sure but if you do koItem.Title(item.Title); 
koItem.RichData(item.Rich); this must work. Please check http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html .. section Reading and writing observables. It could be useful to you

Comment: @G_S Knockout will happily data-bind to non-observable values, you just don't get any updating.  Can you post some sample JSON data that replicates the issue

Comment: The issue with the above code will be the UI wont get updated

Answer (score 0):

In general, with knockout, you should not:

- Call applyBindings more than once
- Call applyBindings inside an ajax call
- Create a viewModel as a plain object (usually, sometimes it's alright)
- Do knockout databinding inside jQuery event handlers.

Code:

```
// this is a reusable view model for each item. it takes a raw item from the ajax return, and creates observables for each property.
var ListItem = function (item) {
    var self = this;
    self.Title = ko.observable(item.Title);
    self.RichData = ko.observable(item.Rich);
}

// Your viewModel. Constructor-esque syntax is pretty standard.
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    // this is your list array.
    self.list = ko.observableArray();

    // This is a your reusable function to load lists, when it returns, it maps each item
    // in data.value to a ListItem viewModel and puts them all in the lists observableArray
    self.loadList = function() {
            $.getJSON('yourUrl', function(data) {
                var items = data.value.map(function(item) { return new ListItem(item); });
                self.list(items);
            }
    };
};

// When the document is ready, create a view model and apply bindings once. Then call loaLists to initialize
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.loadList();
});
```